# Symmetric matrices - eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am trying , without success, to find **Symmetric matrix 2x2** (**Not Diagonal**) with eigenvalues **2** and **3**.

I tried to start from here :

```
Av = 3v  ==> (A-3I)v = 0
Aw = 2w  ==> (A-2I)w = 0
```

It didn't help me.

Your help is appricaited.

Comment: Why not diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a-x & c \\
c & b-x \\
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

The characteristic polynomial will be:

$$(a-x)(b-x)-c^2=0$$

$2$ and $3$ are the roots, so:

$$(a-2)(b-2)-c^2=0 \quad (1)$$

$$(a-3)(b-3)-c^2=0 \quad (2)$$

Then $(1)-(2)$:

$$a+b=5$$

Now choose $a$ and $b$ that fit the above equation and then find $c$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Awesome! , thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Start with the general symmetric matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Calculate its characteristic polynomial and compare it with the characteristic polynomial you want:

$$(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)$$

Then try to choose a, b, c in order to make both polynomials equal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , do you mean (a-λ)(c-λ) - b^2 = (λ−2)(λ−3) ?

Comment: Yes, compare the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spectral theorem with an orthogonal basis different from the standard one:
$$
A=
2
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}
+3
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The companion matrix for $(x-2)(x-3)=x^2-5x+6$ is 
$$ \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -6 & 5 \\
        \end{matrix} \right]
$$
See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html).  I used the transpose of the companion matrix here. It isn't symmetric, but it isn't the identity.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.